# OpenGL Shader Uniform becomes slower

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, gpu

### The Problem

I'm developing some procedural terrain generation in C++ with OpenGL. As an IDE I'm using Microsoft VS2017. I can run the "experiment" without problems. But after about two hours of development the program slows down. Within ten minutes or so, the framerate drops from over 100 to 20. And shortly after that my GPU doesn't manage to render a frame every second. When launching the program, it takes an eternity to load the shaders and link the programs.

### Possible Causes

After some debugging and profiling within VS2017, it turns out that over 98% of the time the CPU is waiting for the GPU to complete shader uniform actions. This includes finding the locations of uniform variables and loading three matricies to uniform variables.

### Troubleshooting Steps

I've tried various different things to improve the situationg including the following ones but I could not fix the problem without restarting my computer

- Copy .exe and assets to another folder
- Copy .exe and assets to another physical devide
- Relaunch VS2017
- Decrease GPU and memory clock in MSI Afterburner
- Check graphics card VRAM usage
- Close background applications

### My Computer

If this information helps someone, here is it:

- Intel© Core© i5-6600K @3,5GHz
- EVGA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5
- MSI Z170-A PRO
- 2x8GB DDR4-2133
- Thermaltake 530W PSU
- 2x1TB HDD in RAID1 (Has the project on it)
- 128GB SSD
- 512GB HDD

Thanks in advance,
Elias

Comment: Without seeing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to give you any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 2):

All of your "troubleshooting" steps are voodoo. It doesn't matter which IDE you use (it's just a glorified editor anyway). It doesn't matter where in the filesystem your executable resides (it's just block of storage device with a page mapping to the OS). Decreasing GPU and/or memory clock help with stability if you're running into thermal problems, but will not influence such creeping performance problems (also if there were a thermal problem, you'd notice it within minutes, not hours).

Sudden drops in performance after a system runs for some time can almost always be attributed to resource exhaustion, forcing the system to swap data around. The cause for resource exhaustion is improper allocation management, i.e. an imbalance between allocating something and freeing it again.

This is what you have to debug. For OpenGL every `glGen…`/`glCreate…` must be balanced by a matching `glDelete…`. For every use of `new` in your code, there must be a balancing `delete` (and for `new …[]` there must be a `delete[] …`).

If you push objects into a container (like `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map` and so on) make sure you also carry out the garbage, i.e. dispose of object you no longer use.